# Handshake failure when requesting nginx server in https protocol

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I'm confronted problem with the https request. The problem is that I'm configuring nginx server to accept https request from applications on windows computers but failed to connect to server. The following are some information on wireshark:

Windows application request:
[image]

Response from server1:
[image]

Yet another server2 response:
[image]

The nginx version on server is 1.12.2 and openssl version is 1.0.1f . Nginx configurations is as below:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/cert.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Information about server1 from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html:

Since I counld not find any client's cipher suites like "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" in server TLSv1.0 . I wonder if it's the difference between languages or softwares that makes the problem happen.

by the way, I have no more information other than request url about server2 and my goal is to deploy server1 to accept requests from windows clients.

Could any one give some advice to solve the problem or provide some clues? thanks very much!

Comment: I found this tool very helpful in finding the right cipers configuration, give the target clients that I expect to support https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ . hope this could help

Comment: (1) Is that really OpenSSL 1.0.1f or are you on a distro (like RHEL/CentOS/Oracle/SL or Debian/Ubuntu/Mint) or similar that _starts_ from an upstream version like 1.0.1f, possibly alters the build settings (e.g. RH's past deletion of EC), and adds backported security patches? (2) Your attempted link to ssllabs does not show any information about your server.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the mistake link to ssllabs. I got information from that link with my server domain not showed above, I should have show screenshots about it. I got the OpenSSL version info using command `openssl version` and it shows `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`. Linux distriction is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found useful nginx configuration with my server. But what confuse me is that I could not found any cipher suites that could match the client's cipher spec. And I found the `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Cipher_names_correspondence_table)  and it seems that there are no corresponding info in OpenSSL column. I wonder how server could handle the request with that cipher suite. @LucaT.

Comment: (1) On Ubuntu `openssl version` only shows the upstream version; to get the actual patched version use the `apt*` tools or `dpkg -s openssl`. But checking launchpad I don't see any recent patches that would affect this. (2) Upstream OpenSSL definitely implements that suite, under the name DES-CBC3-SHA, although some versions disable it due to recent birthday issue (SWEET32); I don't know why the Mozilla website doesn't have it, but see your manpage for ciphers(1) or run `openssl ciphers [-v]`. What if anything appears in the nginx log(s) on the system that doesn't work?

Comment: I finally found out the problem. It's nginx that does not support week ssl cipher suites. I have to recompile nginx to support them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out the reason for the problem. The problem occurred because nginx 1.12.2 does not support week ssl ciphers by default. And the client applicatioin which is built on different version of windows OS like XP provides limited cipher suites such as `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` and `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`. These cipher suites are weak in security. The same problem occurred in IE8 browser. IE8 sometime is not able to visit newer websites.

My solution is to recompile nginx with some extra parameters:

install dependency
`sudo apt-get install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev unzip git`

download nginx
`wget -c https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.12.2.tar.gz
tar zxf nginx-1.12.2.tar.gz`

check openssl version
`dpkg -s openssl`

check openssl support for 3DES
`openssl ciphers -v "3DES"`

download openssl source code  openssl >=1.1.0 don't support 3DES by default
`wget -O openssl.zip -c https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/OpenSSL_1_0_1f.zip
unzip openssl.zip
mv openssl-OpenSSL_1_0_1f/ openssl`

compile and install nginx
`cd nginx-1.12.2
./configure --with-openssl=../openssl --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl-opt='enable-weak-ssl-ciphers'
make 
sudo make install`

With some ssl configuration, the server is able to support https request with 3DES cipher suites.

Thanks!